# Lightning documentation doesn't allow to mark + copy + paste on mobile android device

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, documentation

I'm trying to quote some stuff from the Lightning docu using my mobile device (android, chrome) to answer questions on SFSE.

**Update: this issue seems not to exist in iOS**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_csp.htm

As an unfortunate longpress doesn't allow to mark text. So copy+paste is impossible. Kind of show stopper sometimes and no fun.

I couldn't see a Desktop version link. Is there any? Or a different url?

If not, please Salesforce, change it. This is really an usability handicap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I verified just now that this works correctly under mobile safari and chrome on iOS.

Comment: yepp, I can confirm: it works fine on iPad. Possibly someone with Android could check this up with very low prio. In android, mobile firefox also didn't work for me right from the start, but there is a special reader-mode in which worked (small book-icon in the URL-bar). In mobile android chrome I had no chance.

Comment: Updated question to reduce the scope. Btw. a full-site link or Desktop-Version is always a good idea if there is any chance...

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**:

it works with mobile firefox. So low prio. Possibly a bug of mobile chrome.

Tomorrow I'll check on iOS, if it works there it's possibly good enough.